# Testing Angular directives - Not able to compile directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Here is my test file:

```
describe('Clinical App', function() {

  var  template, element;

  beforeEach(module('clinicalApp'));

  describe('clinicalHeader', function() {
    beforeEach(module('app/views/header.html'));

    beforeEach(inject(function($templateCache, $compile, $rootScope) {
      template = $templateCache.get('app/views/header.html');
      $templateCache.put('views/header.html', template);
      var directive = angular.element('<clinical-header></clinical-header>');
      element = $compile(directive)($rootScope);
      $rootScope.$digest();
    }));

    it('should have a list of links', function() {
      var links = element.find('a');
      expect(links.length).toBe(4);
    });
  });
});
```

I keep getting a `Error: [$compile:multidir] Multiple directives [clinicalHeader, clinicalHeader] asking for template on:` error.  I do not see where I am loading something 2 times.  Could someone please take a look?

Answer (score 0):

The question was unanswerable because you did not have all of the information.  I had a copy of my directive I was testing hidden in the controller folder.  When the app loaded, it was also loading the extra copy of the directive.  Thus I was getting a multiple directive error.